# So, I'm having two problems with this website I'm trying to build. 1. Hamburger menu and 2.Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The menu doesn't seem to be a click and drop down thing, and there are two items misplaced, which just won't seem to stay under the parent ul. I've tried positioning it with both ul and li, but the dot doesn't move, and it doesn't seem to make a dropdown/collapse at all. 
The second problem is the background slideshow, the pictures only flash by quickly, instead of staying and going for a second, or just shows one picture only. Here's the CSS and HTML.

https://jsfiddle.net/pte8nkx9/

```
<div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu"> <br style="clear: right" />    </div>
</nav> <nav class="t3-navbar-collapse navbar-collapse collapse in">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav level0"> </ul> </li> 
<li class="dropdown">    
<a href="/index.php/features" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
<img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-plain/422/06_menu_stack-128.png" alt="Home" style="width:20px;height:20px;top:100px;"> 
<b class="caret"></b></a>


<ul class="level1 dropdown-menu">
<li>
<a href="/index.php/features/scheduling-routing">Womens </a>

</li>
<li display:display:block; float: left;>
<a href="/index.php/features/billing-invoicing">Kids</a>

</li>
<li>
<a href="/index.php/features/mobile-workforce">Mens</a>

</li>
</ul></li>

</nav>
```

As shown, I tried just making a regular vertical menu bar, and replace the top with the hamburger menu icon, thinking it'd drop down/collapse. I basically want it to look like

```
                                                 Icon          Shopping Cart
                                                  Item 1
                                                   Sub Item 1-1
                                                   Sub Item 1-2
                                                  Item 2
                                                  Item 3
                                                  Item 4
```

With the slideshow working on in the background.

Comment: Please can you make the question clearer

Comment: I set this question to unsalvageable because it links to a site promoting a javascript/htmil builder. Please remove the link and reask with the minimal code duplicating the problem.

Comment: Check if your scripts actually load something, this is the weirdest link i've seen: http://mydatanest.com/............/slidemenu_hori.css

Comment: two of them works, and [link]http://mydatanest.com/............/slidemenu_hori.css leads to a network not available on both desktop and mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code here are a few things you can do in an editor like JSfiddle.
There is no need to post `meta` tags in the html section.
There is no need to post links to css and js files. You just put those links in the external resources section. 
Put all your `script` tags in the javascript section.
There is no need to call the `$(function()` function in JS fiddle because the DOM is automatically ready in JS fiddle.
When posting code in stackoverflow do not forget to close your tags. The `<ul>` tag was not closed. 

Do these things in js fiddle and then maybe we can help solve your problem.
[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)